# if statement in C error, executed in Visual Studio professional

Tags: visual-c++

I have a really simple code below, because i'm a java programmer and i'm learning c by myself.

```
/* process stdin */
void second_example(){
    int c, nl;
    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    if (c == '\n')
        ++nl;
    printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

this method will read stdin and print out number of lines in the program. But the if statement is never executed!

Can someone explain why please!! Thanks!

**EDIT**

I think the reason is that c is just never equal \n, i tried

```
int c = getchar();
    if (c == '\n'){
        printf("true");
    }
    else{
        printf("false");
    }
```

and it prints false

Comment: What input are you giving your program?  With that input, when do you *think* you will encounter EOF (End of File)??

Comment: it will never reach EOF, because I'm reading the stdin, it just an end of line, the EOF case that make the loop terminates is when I'm reading a file

Comment: You will need to check for newlines _while_ you are reading input. The input has already run out after your `while` loop. The `if` clause goes into the `while` loop.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Since `'\n' != EOF`, your program never goes outside the `while` loop.